# Perl script not writing to extracted zip file

Tags: perl, zip

I'm writing a perl script to extract a specifically named file from a zip file and write to that extracted file (there's more than that to the script but this is the part that I'm getting stuck on).  The code below is a portion of the perl script.

I cannot figure out why it's not writing to the file!

```
my $zipName = "f:\\data\\archive.zip";
my $destPath = "f:\\data\\dataFile.DAT";
my $tempZip = Archive::Zip->new();
my $dataNum = " 0 0";

        unless ($tempZip->read($zipName) == AZ_OK ) 
        {
            die 'read error';
        }

    my @dataFileMatches = $tempZip->membersMatching( 'dataFile.*\.DAT' );

    my $dataFile;

    if($#dataFileMatches> -1)
    {
        $dataFile = $dataFileMatches[0];

        my $fileContents = $tempZip->contents($dataFile);

        my $newContents = substr $fileContents, 0, 10;
        $newContents = $newContents.$dataNum;

        my $dataFilename = $dataFile ->fileName();
        open(my $fh, '>', $dataFilename) or die "Could not open file '$dataFilename' $!";

        $tempZip->contents($dataFile, $newContents);

        $fileContents = $tempZip->contents($dataFile);

        print "New FileContents -  $fileContents\n";

        #print $fh $newContents;
        #copy($fh, $destPath);
        close $fh;
    }
```

Here is the code that is not being executed:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Copy qw(copy);
use Archive::Zip qw/ :ERROR_CODES :CONSTANTS /;

my $filename = 'dataFile.DAT';
open(my $fh, '>', $filename) or die "Could not open file";

print $fh "test\n";

close $fh;
```

But if I create a dummy TEXT file in the exact same directory that this extracted DAT file is in, it works.

Comment: `print "New FileContents -  $fileContents\n";` writes to `STDOUT`; do you see any output in your terminal?

Comment: Yes, it does print to the terminal correctly but when I look at the file it hasn't changed.

Comment: "when I look at the file it hasn't changed." I'm assuming that the script you're running does not have the line `print $fh $newContents;` commented out. As it is, the code in your question only writes to `STDOUT`.

Comment: There is an example how to unzip a file here: https://api.metacpan.org/source/PHRED/Archive-Zip-1.46/examples/extract.pl
Eventually, you don't have to write the file, but call the extractMember method.

Comment: the "print $fh, $newContents" wasn't working for me so I commented it out and tried "$fileCOntents = $tempZip->contents($dataFile)" instead.

Comment: But you still didn't use the extractMember method. Here is a sniplet of the documentation:

extractMemberWithoutPaths( { memberOrZipName => $memberOrName [, name => $extractedName ] } )

    Extract the given member, or match its name and extract it. Does not use path information (extracts into the current directory)

So your code should read: $tempZip->extractMemberWithoutPaths($fileContents); # extract $fileContents to current working directory

Comment: `print $fh, $newContents;` is incorrect, it should be `print $fh $newContents;` without the comma. Assigning something to `$fileContents` won't write anything to your filehandle, so switching the `print` line to `$fileContents = $tempZip->contents($dataFile);` won't fix your issue. You have to print something to your filehandle `$fh` if you want to write data to your file.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `extractMemberWithoutPaths()` method of Archive::Zip.

Here is how to extract a file:

```perl
#!perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper qw/Dumper/;
use FindBin qw/$Bin/;
use File::Spec;
use Archive::Zip qw/AZ_OK/;

my $zipName = File::Spec->catfile($Bin, '/archive.zip');
my $destPath = File::Spec->catfile($Bin, 'dataFile.DAT');
my $tempZip = Archive::Zip->new();
my $dataNum = " 0 0";

unlink $destPath if -e $destPath;

unless ($tempZip->read($zipName) == AZ_OK ) {
    die 'read error';
}

my @dataFileMatches = $tempZip->membersMatching( {regex => 'dataFile.*\.DAT'} );

$tempZip->extractMemberWithoutPaths($dataFileMatches[0]); # extract $fileContents to current working directory

if ( -e $destPath ) {
    print "file was extracted\n";
}else{
    print "File was not extracted :(\n";
}
```

Comment: I've changed how I extracted it but the new text that I want in the file is still not being written in the file.

I've broken this script down and found that even a simple open and print to the file is not working, however if I switch the file to a text file it works.

Comment: Can you post your broken-down code snippets? Maybe it's some kind of typo. Please feel free to use gist or something like that (https://gist.github.com/).